# VM1673:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<',

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have following JS code for ajax from submission with PHP 8. In chrome browser console , I see following error: VM1673:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "
<fo"... is not valid JSON.

What could be the issue?

```
$('#add-blog1-form').on('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  let formData = new FormData(this);
  let dateTime = new Date();
  formData.append('request', "createBlog1");
  formData.append('datetime', +dateTime);
  $.ajax({
    url: 'action.php',
    type: "POST",
    data:  formData,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData:false,
    success: function(data){
      let json_response = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(json_response);
      if(json_response.status == "success"){
        let forum_category =  $('#category').val();
        window.location = "categories.php?id="+forum_category;
      }else{
        alert("Error");
      }
    },
    error: function(){}
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is generated when you try to convert to json a structure that is not compatible with json, according to this it seems that your error is in

```
let json_response = JSON.parse(data);
```

Probably because the data coming from the server is not proper json